# How to restrict access to the SolrCloud 5.3.x Admin UI?

Tags: solr

I just installed SolrCloud 5.3.x and found that the way to secure the Admin UI has changed. Apparently there is a new plugin which does role based authentication and all info on how to secure the Admin UI found on the net is outdated.

I do not need role based authentication but just simply want to put basic authentication to the Admin UI.

How do I configure SolrCloud 5.3.x in order to restrict access to the Admin UI via Basic Authentication?